# CNN Accuracy not improving

Tags: conv-neural-network, regression, training-data, bounding-box, image-classification

Previously I attempted to build a general purpose CNN that can do image classification. I tested it on playing cards and it works pretty well. I'm now attempting to modify the input and output pipelines so that it can do object localization (return the classs as well as the bounding box data). I don't know why but the model won't train. The accuracy won't improve. Rn the model has two output nodes: classifier head(for the image classes) and regresser head (for BBox). If i modify the regresser head to have 0 units(forcing it to train on only the classes and not on the Bbox) the accurcay of the classifier head improves. All other attempts to modify the hyperparameters have no disernable effect.

The code in question:

`````
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

batch_size = 32
img_shape = 150
class_size = 52
shuffle_val = 200000

checkpoint_path = "D:\Python\Datasets\Playing Cards\My Generated DataSet\Checkpoints\weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.4f}.hdf5"

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('D:\Python\Datasets\Playing Cards\Misc\Images with Black BG\Training\*\*', shuffle = False)

train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(shuffle_val) #accepts shuffle buffer

for i in train_ds.take(10):
    print(i) #prints x number of the paths read. Used to confirm if shuffling is done properly.


print("\n\n Training ds len: ", len(train_ds))


def get_train_Bbox(train_file_path):

    mylabel = tf.strings.split(train_file_path, os.sep)[-1] #returns entire file name
    t_x1 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(mylabel, ",")[2], tf.int32)
    t_y1 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(mylabel, ",")[3], tf.int32)
    t_x2 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(mylabel, ",")[4], tf.int32)
    t_y2 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(mylabel, ",")[5], tf.int32)
    
    return t_x1, t_y1, t_x2, t_y2




def get_label(training_file_path):

    label = tf.strings.split(training_file_path, os.sep)[-1]
    label_class = (tf.strings.split(label, ",")[-2])
    label = label_class
    label = tf.strings.to_number(label, tf.int32) 
    label = tf.one_hot(label, class_size)

    print("from label function,num of classes:", len(label))
    print("Label shape after one-hot encoding:", label.shape)

    return label



def process_image(training_file_path):

    label = get_label(training_file_path)
    img = tf.io.read_file(training_file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (img_shape,img_shape))
    img = tf.image.random_brightness(img, 0.2)
    train_img = img/255

    t_x1, t_y1, t_x2, t_y2 = get_train_Bbox(training_file_path)
    print("Label shape after processing image:", label.shape)
    return train_img, {'classifier_head': label, 'regressor_head': (t_x1, t_y1, t_x2, t_y2)}
    

train_ds = train_ds.map(process_image)

train_ds = train_ds.batch(batch_size)

for img, label in train_ds.take(1):
    print("Training: ", label)




valid_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('D:\Python\Datasets\Playing Cards\Misc\Images with Black BG\Validating\*\*', shuffle = False) 

print("Len of Valid ds:", len(valid_ds))

def get_valid_label(valid_file_path):

    valid_label = tf.strings.split(valid_file_path, os.sep)[-1]
    valid_label_class = (tf.strings.split(valid_label, ",")[-2])
    valid_label = valid_label_class
    valid_label = tf.strings.to_number(valid_label, tf.int32)
    valid_label = tf.one_hot(valid_label, class_size) #review this later
    print("Validation Label shape after one-hot encoding:", valid_label.shape)
    return valid_label




def get_valid_Bbox(valid_file_path):

    v_label = tf.strings.split(valid_file_path, os.sep)[-1] #returns entire file name
    v_x1 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(v_label, ",")[2], tf.int32)
    v_y1 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(v_label, ",")[3], tf.int32)
    v_x2 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(v_label, ",")[4], tf.int32)
    v_y2 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(v_label, ",")[5], tf.int32)
    
    return v_x1, v_y1, v_x2, v_y2



def process_valid_image(valid_file_path):
    valid_label = get_valid_label(valid_file_path)
    valid_img = tf.io.read_file(valid_file_path) #read the actual image file ie. the array
    valid_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(valid_img)
    valid_img = tf.image.resize(valid_img, (img_shape,img_shape))
    valid_img = valid_img/255

    v_x1, v_y1, v_x2, v_y2 = get_train_Bbox(valid_file_path)

    print("Valid Label shape after processing image:", valid_label.shape)

    return valid_img, {'classifier_head': valid_label, 'regressor_head': (v_x1, v_y1, v_x2, v_y2)}


valid_ds = valid_ds.map(process_valid_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE) 
valid_ds = valid_ds.batch(batch_size)


for img, label in valid_ds.take(1):
    print("Valid: ", label)




def build_feature_extractor(inputs):


    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = "relu", input_shape=(img_shape,img_shape,3), padding = "same")(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = "relu", input_shape=(img_shape,img_shape,3), padding = "same")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x)


    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation = "relu", input_shape=(img_shape,img_shape,3), padding = "same")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation = "relu", input_shape=(img_shape,img_shape,3), padding = "same")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x)

    return x



def build_model_adaptor(inputs):

    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation= "relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation= "relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation= "relu")(x)
    
    return x

    
def build_classifier_head(inputs):

    return tf.keras.layers.Dense(52, activation= "softmax", name = 'classifier_head')(inputs)


def build_regressor_head(inputs):
    return tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, name = 'regressor_head')(inputs)


def build_model(inputs):

    feature_extractor = build_feature_extractor(inputs)
    model_adaptor = build_model_adaptor(feature_extractor)
    classification_head = build_classifier_head(model_adaptor)
    regressor_head = build_regressor_head(model_adaptor)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = [classification_head, regressor_head])

    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = {'classifier_head' : 'categorical_crossentropy', 'regressor_head' : 'mse'}, metrics = {'classifier_head' : 'accuracy', 'regressor_head' : 'mse'})

    return model


model = build_model(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(img_shape, img_shape, 3,)))



model.summary()


epochs=25


history = model.fit(train_ds,steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(26000 / float(batch_size))), epochs=epochs,validation_data=valid_ds, validation_steps=int(np.ceil(6500 / float(batch_size))))````




I've changed the kernel sizes, batch sizes, image sizes, epochs, number of layers. Attempted to change the loss from categorical cross entrophy to sparce categorical cross entrophy.

NB. The image data that is being used for training has already been augmented prior to being imported into the code. In the code I am just applying some extra brightness adjustments.
`````